# Unable to start Kestrel when 'dotnet run'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I recently deleted one of the Wi-Fi that was remembered on my computer. Suddenly all projects failed to run.

Here's the console output

```
$ dotnet run
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
      User profile is available. Using '/Users/user/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' as key repository; keys will not be encrypted at rest.
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Unable to start Kestrel.
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found.
To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'.
For more information on configuring HTTPS see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=848054.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.UseHttps(ListenOptions listenOptions, Action`1 configureOptions)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.UseHttps(ListenOptions listenOptions)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.AddressesStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(IServerAddressesFeature addresses, KestrelServerOptions serverOptions, ILogger logger, Func`2 createBinding)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found.
To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'.
For more information on configuring HTTPS see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=848054.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.UseHttps(ListenOptions listenOptions, Action`1 configureOptions)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.UseHttps(ListenOptions listenOptions)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.AddressesStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(IServerAddressesFeature addresses, KestrelServerOptions serverOptions, ILogger logger, Func`2 createBinding)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.RunAsync(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token, String shutdownMessage)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.RunAsync(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.Run(IWebHost host)
   at testing.Program.Main(String[] args) in
```

I was using Visual Studio 2019 for Mac. .NET Core SDK and runtime versions:

```
dotnet --version
2.2.401

dotnet --list-sdks
2.2.401 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]

dotnet --list-runtimes
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.6 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.6 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.6 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

I looked at some stackoverflow answers and they suggest it might be certificate problem. I have tried using the `dotnet dev-certs` tool to solve but it doesn't work. Plus I encountered something strange:

```
dotnet dev-certs https --check --verbose
No valid certificate found.

dotnet dev-certs https
A valid HTTPS certificate is already present.

dotnet dev-certs https --trust
Trusting the HTTPS development certificate was requested. If the certificate is not already trusted we will run the following command:
'sudo security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain <<certificate>>'
This command might prompt you for your password to install the certificate on the system keychain.
A valid HTTPS certificate is already present.
```

The `dev-certs` checking option produce contradicting results with command that create the new search

The `dotnet-dev-certs` version is `2.2.0`

In my keychain, there is no certificate for localhost. Then I tried re-installing the dotNET SDKs and Visual Studio but also doesn't work.

Comment: If I were you I'd forget SSL on kestrel. Such lightweight containers are better suited for HTTP only connections and another Web Server can be used to further expose the app, outside of the machine you install it into. IIS or Nginx would do.

Comment: Great! I have used Nginx and worked! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

I'm going through same problem and finally, I relief from this doing 2 things in command prompt.

1. dotnet dev-certs https --clean
2. dotnet dev-certs https --trust

C:\Users\saifs>dotnet dev-certs https --clean
Cleaning HTTPS development certificates from the machine. A prompt might get displayed to confirm the removal of some of the certificates.

C:\Users\saifs>dotnet dev-certs https
The HTTPS developer certificate was generated successfully.

C:\Users\saifs>dotnet dev-certs https --trust
Trusting the HTTPS development certificate was requested. A confirmation prompt will be displayed if the certificate was not previously trusted. Click yes on the prompt to trust the certificate.
A valid HTTPS certificate is already present.